# Do I need root access for Chef deployment scripts execution

Tags: linux

Do I need to have root access for deploying my application on Linux through Chef-solo. Though the Chef solo was installed previously by user with root privileges.

Comment: This will depend on how you have Chef set up and where your application is being deployed to. Are you running chef-client as a service? What is your application and how are you deploying it? Who does it run as? What are the permissions on the directory where it lives? Does anything require restarting to pick up the changes? Need a lot more information here!

Answer (score 0):

Chef client is typical linux app. If someone install it for you and add +x privileges for your user on chef-client file and you can read and write to chef temp folder - you can use it. 
If you want use chef-client with root privileges, but don't want use root user - you can set setuid and setguid bit on chef-client file.